# on scroll add BUTTON on fixed-top navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed fixed-top Navigation Bar by using Bootstrap

[Here is source of used code:][1]

So when user Scrolls down it should show "Add to cart" Button on Nav Bar. 
 ![enter image description here][2]

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you should put your "Add to cart" to exact place in your layout.
2. set it `display:none`
3. put some class with `display:block` in your css, for example `active`
4. set you scroll event to add `active` class to your button class

here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJuarez/ka5n6u3t/

Comment: thank you for your help. Now I Want add line between link and cart icon.
also one line at bottom